# unable to fetch current location in android after installing second time

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

Im developing a uber clone app the problem im facing is as mentioned above when i install the app on a device on which it isnt installed already it fetches my current location and shows and even tracks my movements, but when i log out or come out of the app the isnt even showing my current location. it just shows the african continent.
**code below , the activity which should fetch location**

```
 package com.example.uber_clone;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.uber_clone.DriverLogin;
import com.example.uber_clone.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import static com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.*;

public class Map_Driver extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private   Location mLastLocation;
    private  LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private  FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    private int status = 0;

    private String customerId = "", destination;
    private LatLng destinationLatLng, pickupLatLng;
    private float rideDistance;



    Button logout_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map__driver);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        logout_btn = findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        logout_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Map_Driver.this, DriverLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });



    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if(VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            }else{
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
    }


    LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for(Location location : locationResult.getLocations()){
                if(getApplicationContext()!=null){

//                    if(!customerId.equals("") && mLastLocation!=null && location != null){
//                        rideDistance += mLastLocation.distanceTo(location)/1000;
//                    }
                    mLastLocation = location;


                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

//                    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
//                    DatabaseReference refAvailable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");
//                    DatabaseReference refWorking = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversWorking");
//                    GeoFire geoFireAvailable = new GeoFire(refAvailable);
//                    GeoFire geoFireWorking = new GeoFire(refWorking);
//
//                    switch (customerId){
//                        case "":
//                            geoFireWorking.removeLocation(userId);
//                            geoFireAvailable.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
//                            break;
//
//                        default:
//                            geoFireAvailable.removeLocation(userId);
//                            geoFireWorking.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
//                            break;
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Grant Location Permissions")
                        .setMessage("Please Grant Location Permission, Or Else App Might Not Work")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Map_Driver.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
            else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Map_Driver.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch(requestCode){
            case 1:{
                if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

*im a newbee , any help is much appreciated . thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to initialize your map again in your `onResume` function of your activity.

Comment: @ReazMurshed could you please write a detailed answer please.

Comment: In that case, I need to see where you are initializing the map. Can you please add that in your question as well?

Comment: i have added the whole code . please have a look. thanks